# Does Playwright offer custom args in the command line?

Tags: playwright

I want to create custom args in the commandline so that my same specs, when the process.argv matches the custom args, does slightly different things. But I couldn't see that option in the docs. Did I miss it or is this not allowed in Playwright?

Answer (score 2):

It seems not possible at this moment. I tried to add my option after `--`, which terminates original options list, but then those are considered to be arguments to filter files.

Now, I use environmental variables instead. You can define them in .env file and use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to load it. Then, they will be available through `process.env`.

```ts
import * as dotenv from "dotenv"

export default async function globalSetup() {
    const output = dotenv.config()
    console.log(output.parsed)
    console.log(process.env.MY_ENV_VAR)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not clear exactly what you mean, but playwright does support custom launch arguments for chrome along with a multitude of other [launch options](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch).

Comment: In Protractor I can do this: 
`protractor qe/configs/protractor.conf.js --caps=localWideView --backendService=real-api-service  --localOrSauceLabs=local --suite accessibility`

Here "caps", "backendService" and "loalOrSauceLabs" are all my own custom arguments. Is there something like that in Playwright like:
`npx playwright test --config=qe/configs/playwright.config.medium.ts --caps=localMediumView --backendService=real-api-service  --localOrSauceLabs=local`